# how to convert spreadsheet columns to rows using Java

Tags: java, spreadsheet

My application allows users to upload a spreadsheet and will process the sheet row wise. Now I need to develop an application to process a spreadsheet column wise. Is there a way to convert all the columns to rows using java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apache POI for doing this

http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Im using this API.. but is there any method to convert columns to rows?

Comment: I think their is no direct method available for doing this. You should iterate through rows and convert it into rows.